# How to work with ExpandableListView inside SwipeRefreshLayout which in turn inside of CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, android-coordinatorlayout, swiperefreshlayout

A WebView(that contains vimeo or youtube video) which is wrapped inside RelativeLayout along with some TextViews will be added to **postViewContainer** programatically. Sometimes, it's just some TextViews and ImageViews but most of the time, it has a WebView.

**videoFullScreenContainer** is used when a video is enlarged into full screen mode

**eplComments** contains a list of comments. Each comment has a list of replies.

The problem here is the **postViewContainer** is not a part of scrollable. Even **eplComments** is not working well. When scrolling up, it triggers *pull to refresh* before it is scrolled all the way up.

How do I make **postViewContainer** a part of scrollable and solve the scrolling conflict with SwipeRefreshLayout?

**postViewContainer** can't be an item of **eplComments** because if it is, the video inside the webview reloads whenever items in **eplComments** are updated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            ...

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/postViewContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </FrameLayout>

                <ExpandableListView
                    android:id="@+id/eplComments"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                    android:childDivider="@null"
                    android:divider="@null"
                    android:groupIndicator="@null"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoFullScreenContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

updated:
I have also tried wrapping the content of SwipeRefreshLayout in NestedScrollView like below. The problem here is it loads only the first item in the ExpandableListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            ...

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/postViewContainer"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    </FrameLayout>

                    <ExpandableListView
                        android:id="@+id/eplComments"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                        android:childDivider="@null"
                        android:divider="@null"
                        android:groupIndicator="@null"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoFullScreenContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `postViewContainer` and its container(LinearLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            ...

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/eplComments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:childDivider="@null"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:groupIndicator="@null"
                />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoFullScreenContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add the WebView(along with any other views you want to add programatically) to the ExpandableListView as header

```
mExpandableListView.addHeaderView(view);
```